# AngularJs UI router "Link to Previous Page" to not to reload the previous page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular UI-ROUTER to transition from one route to another route. I am transitioning from  Page 1 to Page 2. The Page 2 has a link "return to previous page" . I expect that when the user User clicks on that link ("return to previous page"), then Page 1 should be shown without reload.

I used "history.back" with no success.

```
<a href="#/my_devices/all_devices" on-click="history.back()" ></a>
```

Please Help

Comment: It will be nice to know the version of both (angular and ui-router)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with state change events, and set the previous state to a variable

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    $rootScope.previousState = {state: fromState, params: fromParams};
  });

$rootScope.backState = function(state, params) {
    $state.go(state.name, params);
};
```

and in your view

```
<a href="#" on-click="backState(previousState.state, previousState.params)"></a>
```

If you have a `header` component is better to use the header `scope` (in place of rootScope), otherwise put this on the `.run()` method, and you have the variables set for all scopes.

Comment: I tried it . I did $rootScope.$on on App.run. But the previous page is still getting refreshed

Answer (score 0):

You are using a link which could link to two different pages. Just do this instead:

```
<a href="#/path/to/page1">Previous page</a>
```

or, since you are using ui-router, if you defined Page 1's state to be 'page1', ie if you did this:

```
angular.module('someModule')
  .state('page1', {
    url: '/path/to/page1',
    etc...
  });
```

Then you can just do:

```
<a ui-sref="page1">Previous page</a>
```

Angular is made for Single Page Applications (SPAs) so there shouldn't be any page reload or refresh